# MATLAB table Column Headers

Tags: matlab

I am working in MATLAB and trying to add units to the Column headers to a table of values, e.g 'Time[s]', but this is invalid because of the []. According to everything I've found thus far has said that column headers must be valid variable names, e.g. alphanumeric and "_" only. Does anyone know of a work-around to add units to the titles that are obviously units? I would need either [] or (), / and * to cover all possible units.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For tables it is true that the column names have to be valid variable names (as you've found) and none of the characters you've mentioned are allowed in variable names in MATLAB. If you want to include unit information with your columns, you'll want to use the [`VariableUnits`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/modify-units-descriptions-and-table-variable-names.html#zmw57dd0e22652) of the table properties to specify these.

```
t = table(rand(10, 1), 'VariableNames', {'Time'});
t.Properties.VariableUnits = {'sec'};
```

You could also modify the `VariableDescriptions`.

```
t.Properties.VariableDescriptions = {'Time (s)'};
```

Then when you view the summary data, the units and your custom description will be shown.

```
summary(t)

%// Variables:
%// 
%// Time: 10x1 double
%// Units:  sec
%// Description:  Time (s)
%// Values:
%//
%//     min       0.11437
%//     median     0.4344
%//     max       0.96995
```

**Update**

If you really wanted to, you would need to use variable names that are valid but convey the units (i.e. `Time_sec`)

Comment: This is not quite what I wanted, I want to be able to see the units in the table without going into the summary just at a glance. Is this not possible?

Comment: It is not possible because of the first sentence in my answer. Only the variable names are shown at the tops of the columns. You would need to use something like `Time_sec` for the variable names